# com.google.gson.JsonArray.getAsString error on fullTextQuery.getResultList() in Hibernate Search query

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene, hibernate-search

I'm trying to fetch data from idexes with a hibernate search fulltext query.
Below is the index structure:

```
 {
    "_index" : "basclt1400",
    "_type" : "com.csc.pt.svc.data.to.Basclt1400TO",
    "_id" : "00,0006682,CPP,05,00",
    "_score" : 1.0,
    "_source" : {
      "id" : "00,0006682,CPP,05,00",
      "location" : "00",
      "master0co" : "05",
      "policy0num" : "0006682",
      "symbol" : "CPP",
      "module" : "00",
      "cltseqnum" : 281,
      "addrseqnum" : "1",
      "policies_location" : [
        "00",
        "00"
      ],
      "policies_master0co" : [
        "05",
        "05"
      ],
      "policies_policy0num" : [
        "0006682",
        "0006682"
      ],
      "policies_trans0stat" : [
        "V",
        "P"
      ],
      "policies_id02" : [
        "02",
        "02"
      ],
      "policies_symbol" : [
        "CPP",
        "CPP"
      ],
      "policies_module" : [
        "00",
        "00"
      ],
      "policies_tot0ag0prm" : [
        "1532.00",
        "1532.00"
      ],
      "policies_issue0code" : [
        "N",
        "N"
      ],
      "policies_id" : [
        "02,00,0006682,CPP,05,00,V",
        "02,00,0006682,CPP,05,00,P"
      ]
    }
```

This structure may  change as per data under the index, at some places the data under "policies_policy0num" field there may be just one record, like below, and it works fine with this structure:

```
"_index" : "basclt1400",
    "_type" : "com.csc.pt.svc.data.to.Basclt1400TO",
    "_id" : "00,0012410,CPP,05,00",
    "_score" : 1.0,
    "_source" : {
      "id" : "00,0012410,CPP,05,00",
      "location" : "00",
      "master0co" : "05",
      "policy0num" : "0012410",
      "symbol" : "CPP",
      "module" : "00",
      "cltseqnum" : 281,
      "addrseqnum" : "1",
      "policies_location" : [
        "00"
      ],
      "policies_master0co" : [
        "05"
      ],
      "policies_policy0num" : [
        "0012410"
      ],
      "policies_trans0stat" : [
        "P"
      ],
      "policies_id02" : [
        "02"
      ],
      "policies_symbol" : [
        "CPP"
      ],
      "policies_module" : [
        "00"
      ],
      "policies_tot0ag0prm" : [
        "0.00"
      ],
      "policies_issue0code" : [
        "N"
      ],
      "policies_id" : [
        "02,00,0012410,CPP,05,00,P"
      ]
    }
  }
```

I'm trying to fetch this like below:

```
Iterator itr = fullTextQuery.getResultList().iterator();
        List<MasterSearchPmsp0200DataArr> policyArrayFinal = new ArrayList<MasterSearchPmsp0200DataArr>();
        List<MasterSearchPmsp0200DataArr> quoteArrayFinal = new ArrayList<MasterSearchPmsp0200DataArr>();
        while(itr.hasNext()){
           Object[] obj = (Object[]) itr.next();
           char issueCode = (char) obj[5];
           if(issueCode == 'N' || issueCode == 'R') {
               policyArrayFinal.add( new MasterSearchPmsp0200DataArr((String) obj[0], Long.valueOf(to.getCltseqnum()), 
                        (String) obj[1], (String) obj[2], (String) obj[3], (String) obj[4],
                        (char) obj[5], (char) obj[6]));
           }else {
               quoteArrayFinal.add( new MasterSearchPmsp0200DataArr((String) obj[0], Long.valueOf(to.getCltseqnum()), 
                        (String) obj[1], (String) obj[2], (String) obj[3], (String) obj[4],
                        (char) obj[5], (char) obj[6])); 
           }

           }
```

and it's throwing the below error, just for the records where we have multiple data under policies_policy0num.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException
at com.google.gson.JsonArray.getAsString(JsonArray.java:226)
at org.hibernate.search.elasticsearch.query.impl.PrimitiveProjection.addDocumentField(PrimitiveProjection.java:69)
at org.hibernate.search.elasticsearch.query.impl.PrimitiveProjection.addDocumentField(PrimitiveProjection.java:43)
at org.hibernate.search.elasticsearch.query.impl.TwoWayFieldBridgeProjection.convertFieldValue(TwoWayFieldBridgeProjection.java:60)
at org.hibernate.search.elasticsearch.query.impl.TwoWayFieldBridgeProjection.convertHit(TwoWayFieldBridgeProjection.java:43)
at org.hibernate.search.elasticsearch.query.impl.QueryHitConverter.convert(QueryHitConverter.java:186)
at org.hibernate.search.elasticsearch.query.impl.IndexSearcher.convertQueryHit(IndexSearcher.java:138)
at org.hibernate.search.elasticsearch.query.impl.ElasticsearchHSQueryImpl.queryEntityInfos(ElasticsearchHSQueryImpl.java:233)
at org.hibernate.search.query.hibernate.impl.FullTextQueryImpl.doHibernateSearchList(FullTextQueryImpl.java:238)
at org.hibernate.search.query.hibernate.impl.FullTextQueryImpl.list(FullTextQueryImpl.java:223)
at org.hibernate.search.query.hibernate.impl.FullTextQueryImpl.getResultList(FullTextQueryImpl.java:122)
```

Attaching the error point snaspshot:
[error snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tovMY.png)
How should I handle this scenario under hibernate search java code.

Adding the query code:

```
Query query = queryBuilder.keyword().onField("cltseqnum").matching(to.getCltseqnum()).createQuery();

        FullTextQuery fullTextQuery = fullTextSession.createFullTextQuery(query, Basclt1400TO.class);
        fullTextQuery.setProjection( "policies_policy0num", "policies_symbol", 
                "policies_module", "policies_master0co","policies_location", "policies_issue0code",
                "policies_trans0stat");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't provide the code used to build the query, but from what I can see you are using projections.

Projections do not support multi-valued fields, so you simply cannot make this work, unless you project on the whole document (using `org.hibernate.search.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchProjectionConstants.SOURCE`) and parse it yourself, which would be a terrible hack.

I would recommend using "traditional" entity loading (without projections) and getting the data from your entities. Unless you've got tremendous performance constraints, this should result in decent performance, especially if you tune your Hibernate ORM mapping correctly.

Comment: Thank You Yoann. But the reason I was using the projections was to avoid the call to the actual database. And would rather retrieve the data from elastic DB only. I do not want the call to Actual DB.
How would I achieve that without projections, as without projections its going to actual DB too.

Comment: @ONS Then your only course of action, in Hibernate Search 5, is to use `fulltextQuery.setProjection( org.hibernate.search.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchProjectionConstants.SOURCE )`. You will get the full JSON document as a String in the projection results. You will have to parse JSON yourself instead of just letting Hibernate ORM build objects, and performance probably won't be wonderful either, so in the end I doubt you will gain anything. But I guess that's none of my business :)

Comment: thank you for the wise words. Greatly appreciate your time.